# Angular circular reference when using $http to log exceptions

Tags: angularjs

I'm overriding the Angular $exceptionHandler to do some custom logging of exceptions.  Unfortunately, my Logging service uses $http for logging, which is dependent on $exceptionHandler.  Any thoughts on a pattern that would resolve my circular reference and still allow me to log via $http?

Here is my Service overriding $exceptionHandler:

```
angular.module('dashboard').factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', 'Logging', 
function($log, Logging){
    return  function globalErrorHandler(exception, cause){
        var itemToLog = new logItem('dashboard', 'General Error', exception.message + ": " + exception.stack);
        Logging.logEvent(itemToLog);
        $log.warn(exception, cause);
    }
}]);
```

and my custom Logging service:

```
angular.module('dashboard').factory('Logging', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        logEvent: function(item){
            $http.post('/api/loggingservice/event', item)
                .success(function(data){
                    return data;
                }).
            error(function(data){
                console.log('error logging event: '+JSON.stringify(data));
            });;
        }
    };
}]);
```

And the error message I receive is:
    angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep]
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=$http%20%3C-%20Logging%20%3C-%20$exceptionHandler%20%3C-%20$rootScope%20%3C-%20$http%20%3C-%20UserManagement%20%3C-%20Menus

Comment: Please, update the question with error message you're getting. This will make it more clear and easier to find.

Comment: I've added the error message, and I'm testing out your answer - which looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$exceptionHandler` is used by other core services that `$http` depends on. This makes injecting `$http` or a service that depends on `$http` impossible, because this results in circular dependency.

A usual recipe to avoid CD in Angular 1 is using `$injector.get(...)` instead of injecting a service in service factory/constructor function. However, the developer should be aware why it is done and what it is going on there.

Doing something like

```
function($log, $injector){
    var Logging = $injector.get('Logging');
    return  function globalErrorHandler(exception, cause){ ... }
}
```

won't break circular dependency, because `$exceptionHandler` is eagerly instantiated by core services which `$http` depends on, which `Logging` depends on.

On the other hand,

```
function($log, $injector){
    return  function globalErrorHandler(exception, cause){
        var Logging = $injector.get('Logging');
        ...
    }
}
```

will work because this way `Logging` is lazily instantiated. This will result in executing `$injector.get(...)` on each handler call. But this is fine, since `$injector.get(...)` has no performance impact and can be called multiple times, especially in non-critical places.